# Tinymce, disable numlist dropdown

Tags: php, styles, tinymce

Is it possible to disable the dropdown for the numlist button on tinymce? And if so, how?

Thanks in advance.

**Due to the first answer:**
theme_advanced_disable is not the answer to my question. It removes the button completely. What i need to do is to disable the dropdown where you can select the list types. Only the standard type should be allowed, no other selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution after long time...

---

1. load original plugin
2. define toolbar without '*bullist'*, but with your own button *'mylist'*
3. define button *'mylist'* which will call original plugin function (readed from original *lists/plugin.min.js*)

**Full code:**

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: ["lists"],
    //toolbar1: "bullist numlist",
    toolbar1: "mylist numlist",

    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.addButton('mylist', {
            text: '',   //without text label
            icon: 'bullist',    //use original icon
            tooltip: 'Bullet list',     //tooltip, if you want
            onclick: function() {
                //call original plugin function
                tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('InsertUnorderedList');        
            }
        });
    },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Just delete advlist plugin in init function

Answer (score 0):

with `theme_advanced_disable` ?

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        theme_advanced_disable : "numlist"
});
```

Comment: i want to keep the button, **only** disable the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked `List Style Options` in Setting page under `Advanced Editor Tools`.